# Woocommerce - Remove "buy now" button from related products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

[Here](http://www.happyhealthymarket.com/) is my site.

I used the following code to add a buy it now button to my product archives page:

```
/** Add buy it now to shop page **/

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
```

Now the button shows up on my related products (See [here](http://www.happyhealthymarket.com/product/worlds-first-bluetooth-smart-fork/)), but I only want it to show on the single product page and archive/category pages.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing that would be by adding the following to the css file:

```
div.related.products > ul > li > a.button.add_to_cart_button 
{
    display: none;
}
```

While this isn't removing the button, it is hiding it so it's not seen.

EDIT:

```
div.related.products > ul.products > li > a.button.product_type_external
{
    display: none;
}
```